# ScrollView isn't resizing properly

Tags: ios, autolayout, scrollview, orientation

I have a ScrollView with vertical scrolling. The reason for the ScrollView is to fit all of my buttons when the orientation changes to landscape.

There are 2 problems that are possibly linked:

- When in portrait (with no need for scrolling) the view still wants to scroll.
- When in landscape, it leaves too much scrolling space at the bottom.

Constraints:

- ScrollView - Trailing/Leading space to superView, Bottom space to label2, Top space to label1
- ContentView - Trailing/Leading/Bottom/Top space to superView, Width equal to mainView
- Label1 - Align Center X, Top space to superView (60), Bottom space to scrollView
- Label2 - Align Center X, Bottom space to superView (60), Top space to scrollView
- Buttons - Align Center X, Top space to superView (50), Height equals (50), Bottom space to other button (30) or Bottom space to superView (50)

Adjust Scroll View Insets is unchecked. Its all in autolayout, no code.

View Controller Example:

[image]

What's strange, is that I have other perfectly working scroll views that resize accordingly. When trying to duplicate the process, I kept getting the same results...

Looked around, but haven't been able to find any helpful answers. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'll add other information if needed. I'm sure its a simple solution that I keep overlooking -_-

Comment: Try getting rid of `Height equal to superView (priority 250)`. Not sure why that's there.

Comment: @MihaiFratu I think I added that as one of my fix attempts that I just left. So I did get rid of it just now, not making a difference tho. I'll edit it out of my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor scroll view leading and width to view's leading and width; anchor top to label1 bottom and bottom to label2 top.

Get rid of the content view (not needed). Add everything to the scroll view.

Anchor button1 center-x to scroll view center-x and top to scroll view top. If you need to give button1 width or height using constraints, do not use the scroll view's width or height; instead, anchor the button's width to the view's width, height to view's height. Subviews of scroll view should not rely on the scroll view to determine their sizes.

Anchor button4 top to button3 bottom, center-x to scroll view center-x; and most importantly, anchor button4 bottom to scroll view bottom (this will stretch the scroll view for you). This will prevent scrolling when scrolling isn't needed.

Comment: The problem is, that every scrollView tutorial, and my previous views use some sort of a contentView inside the scrollView. I tried your solution, but it gives me a 'scroll view has ambiguous scrollable content width' warning.

Comment: That's not true, the faux content view is sometimes used in Apple's examples and sometimes isn't. Apple does not require it or even recommended it. Their tutorials say you can create one if you wish, or not. As to your warning, you must anchor subviews of scroll view to left and right also, not just top and bottom so that the scroll view knows how far to stretch horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Ah ok. That worked. I though I read about there being a problem putting everything straight into the scrollView, but seems I was wrong. Thanks! Now I just have to fix the buttons from stretching -_-  .. But that's a different issue.

Comment: Just add a negative constant to their width anchors. Or create a faux content view and give that a width of the view and add the buttons to the content view. The bottom line is to make sure all anchors touch all sides of the scroll view.

Comment: If I add a content view, it seems I'll have the same problem as i started with, but I'll try the other solutions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that your "Bottom space to superView (50) in buttons" is ambiguos, I recommend delete it, the other problem is that your contentView doesn't know its real position, try to add "Center X and Y of your contentView with your scrollView".